# Exclude all files in a filelist

Tags: ant

I have a file list as given below which is used by an existing target.
I want to write a new target which zips all files from the directory files except files which is given in the filelist (properties).

```
<filelist id="excludesFiles" dir="${client.config.dir}" files="audit.properties,configuration.xml,portal.properties,services.xml,torque.properties,turbine.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your fileset as follows

```
<filelist id="zipfiles" dir="${client.config.dir}" excludes="audit.properties,configuration.xml,portal.properties,services.xml,torque.properties,turbine.properties"/>

<zip destfile="abc.zip"
   <fileset refid="zipfiles"/>
</zip>
```

The fileset now includes all files in the config dir except the ones given in the excludes list.